# Build iOS app with Notification Extension with fastlane

Tags: ios, provisioning, fastlane

I recently added a notification extension to my app which was built well with fastlane. After adding the notification extension the building is always failing because of some code signing issue.

The lane for building my app and uploading it to TestFlight is:

```
    lane :beta do
         increment_build_number(
            build_number: latest_testflight_build_number + 1,
            xcodeproj: "ios.xcodeproj"
         )
         match(app_identifier: ["my.app.bundleid", "my.app.bundleid.extension" type: "appstore") 
         gym(scheme: "prod")
         ENV["DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS"] = "-t DAV"
         pilot(
           skip_submission: true,
           skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
         ) 
    end
```

I have created the App IDs and provisioning profiles for both bundle ids and I have enabled the push notification for both of them.

Even though I am getting the following error after running `fastlane beta`:

```
[19:13:20]: $ /usr/bin/xcrun /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.96.1/gym/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist '/var/folders/vq/j6j2lh1s3cz7cbpw7shc9149fy4t4_/T/gym_config20180601-5305-a3y0ow.plist' -archivePath /Users/viktor.plezer/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-06-01/prod\ 2018-06-01\ 19.07.57.xcarchive -exportPath '/var/folders/vq/j6j2lh1s3cz7cbpw7shc9149fy4t4_/T/gym_output20180601-5305-ghy31c' 
+ xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/vq/j6j2lh1s3cz7cbpw7shc9149fy4t4_/T/gym_config20180601-5305-a3y0ow.plist -archivePath '/Users/viktor.plezer/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-06-01/prod 2018-06-01 19.07.57.xcarchive' -exportPath /var/folders/vq/j6j2lh1s3cz7cbpw7shc9149fy4t4_/T/gym_output20180601-5305-ghy31c
2018-06-01 19:13:21.181 xcodebuild[7741:1606819] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/vq/j6j2lh1s3cz7cbpw7shc9149fy4t4_/T/prod_2018-06-01_19-13-21.180.xcdistributionlogs'.
2018-06-01 19:13:25.613 xcodebuild[7741:1606819] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7ff969a6c950>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
"Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"prod.app\" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"prod.app\" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the \"provisioningProfiles\" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}"
)}
error: exportArchive: "prod.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""prod.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="prod.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

** EXPORT FAILED **
[19:13:26]: Exit status: 70
[19:13:26]: No provisioning profile provided
[19:13:26]: Make sure to pass a valid provisioning for each required target
[19:13:26]: Check out the docs on how to fix this: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/#export-options
```

I have added both bundle ids into my Matchfile, fastlane can download the certs correctly.

provisioningProfiles dict looks like:

```
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸ <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸ <plist version="1.0">
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸ <dict>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸    <key>method</key>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸    <string>app-store</string>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸    <dict>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸        <key>my.app.bundleid.extension</key>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸        <string>match AppStore my.app.bundleid.extension</string>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸        <key>my.app.bundleid</key>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸        <string>match AppStore my.app.bundleid</string>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸    </dict>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸    <key>signingStyle</key>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸    <string>manual</string>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸ </dict>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸ </plist>
INFO [2018-06-01 20:08:45.03]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
```

Why does fastlane start to search for provisioning profile for prod.app and not my.app.bundleid?

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution yet? (The accepted answer is not working for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the exact error I was receiving and the issue in my case was an invalid value for `CFBundleIdentifier` in the extension's plist file. Once I changed it to the below, the build succeeded:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

Comment: Hey Brad! Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the project where the issue was present, but as the one and only responder to this question, I accept your answer! :)

Comment: @viplezer Thanks! :-)

Comment: In my case, I was just having a bad configuration. I messed with pbxproj file & got PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER missing so the $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) was empty & messing everything up.